# SQL Distinct Question

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

So I'm tired, but why isn't DISTINCT working here:

```
      SELECT DISTINCT Review.user_id, Review.id, User.*, Account.* 
      FROM reviews As Review 
      INNER JOIN users AS User ON Review.user_id = User.id 
      LEFT JOIN accounts AS Account ON User.id = Account.user_id
```

Comment: Define "isn't working" - not the expected results or an error?

Comment: some tables structure/sample data would help

Comment: Not the expected results.  I have a limit set on it to three, but get the same user_id back each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only unique user_id's, try GROUP'ing by it. But this will truncate all other joined records from the result. So you better think what do you want to select with user_id and what you don't.

```
  SELECT DISTINCT Review.user_id, Review.id, User.*, Account.* 
  FROM reviews As Review 
  INNER JOIN users AS User ON Review.user_id = User.id 
  LEFT JOIN accounts AS Account ON User.id = Account.user_id 
  GROUP BY Review.user_id
```

Answer (score 5):

Since the Unique only works on the result which are exactly same. But here you are including `ID`s as well, which will be unique for each row making each record unique. So the result is showing all the records.

Comment: so if i put a limit of 4 on there, how do i ensure that i get 4 reviews from 4 different users

Comment: Please comment when you vote -ve. Thanks.